# Java: How can I get the connected port from an InetAddress?

Tags: java, sockets, apache-mina

I'm trying to build a Java NIO-based socket server using Apache Mina.  I really need to know the port of the remote host, not just the IP address, and it seems that Mina only exposes a SocketAddress (which can be downcast to InetAddress) object.  I can get the IP address from InetAddress, but I normally use Socket.getPort() to get the port number, but Mina appears to obscure these low-level objects.  Is there another way?  Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Downcast the `SocketAddress` to [`InetSocketAddress`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html) (not [`InetAddress`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html), which is *not* a sub-class); this exposes a [`port` accessor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html#getPort()).

Answer (score 7):

I have a real old version but this worked for me,

```
public int getPort(SocketAddress address) {
    return ((InetSocketAddress) address).getPort();
}
```